# Частица "де"

Tags: этимология, пунктуация

Есть в русском языке некие частица (впрочем, я не знаю, чем они являются в предложении), которые образовались от сокращения слов. Например, "мол" - от "молвит", как я понимаю. А от какого слова произошла частица "де" и как она пишется со словами: раздельно или через дефис? "Он(-)де знает, как это делается".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От "дескать". Пишется всегда через дефис.

Comment: Мне тут правку предложили: *"если не стоит после еще одной частицы (по версии грамота.ру). Например, в этом случае пишется раздельно: все же таки, он бы де этого не сказал."* Ничего не имею против дополнения, но ответ получается явно не мой.  Посему выношу в комментарий.

Comment: И отвечаю. Не уверен, что "Грамота" права. Надо разбираться. Пример мне кажется надуманным. В принципе такое правило есть про частицы http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm, но может ли "де" в нормальной речи оказаться именно в таком положении - вопрос.